# (From Axler)Why does these two proof of these questions not contradict to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Here are the solutions to these 2 questions:

http://linearalgebras.com/3A.html

(Axler 3A 10)
Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ with $U≠V$ Suppose $S∈L(U,W)$ and $S≠0$ (which means that $Su≠0$ for some $u∈U$). Define $T:V→W$ by

$Tv$=$Sv$ if $v∈U$ and
$Tv$=$0$ ,if $v∉U$

Prove that $T$ is not a linear map on $V$.

11. Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Prove that every linear map on a subspace of $V$ can be extended to a linear map on $V$. In other words, show that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $S∈L(U,W)$, then there exists $T∈L(V,W)$ such that $Tu=Su$ for all $u∈U$.

I know the theorem in Axler 3.5 and I can understand and agree with the proof. But the question 10 contradicts question 11 since the map in 11 is proved to be not linear in question 10.

I wonder where is wrong or I misunderstood something. Could someone explain the subtle difference?

Comment: This map in (10) has an additional stipulation as to what $T$ does outside of $U$. Try a simple example: take $V =W= \mathbb R^2$ and $U =$ the $x$-axis. Let $S$ be the inclusion.

Comment: I have addressed the distinction between this number $10$ and the number $11$ problems in Axler *in detail* at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918002/extending-a-linear-map/1918517#1918517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map in question 11 is not the same as the one in question 10. In question 10, the map has to be zero for all $v$ outside of $U$, whereas this is not required of the map in question $11$.